# Can I fold with an infix operator without writing out an anonymous function?

Tags: sml, syntactic-sugar

If I wanted to add up a list I could do this:

```
- List.foldr (fn (x, y) => x + y) 0 [1, 2, 3]
val it = 6 : int
```

Is there any way to write something more along the lines of:

```
List.foldr + 0 [1, 2, 3]
```

I tried something like this:

```
fun inf2f op = fn (x, y) => x op y;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close. Add the `op` keyword in the second example.

```
- List.foldr op + 0 [1,2,3];
val it = 6 : int
```

Comment: follow-up, is there one like `(?? f)` which stands for `(fn x => f x)`?

Comment: Uh... Isn't that just `f`?

Comment: @brian, just for the sake of correctness. `op` is a keyword just as `if`, `with` and `open` are. Not an operator.